# find minimum step to make a number from a pair of number

Tags: algorithm, math

Let's assume that we have a pair of numbers (a, b). We can get a new pair (a + b, b) or (a, a + b) from the given pair in a single step.

Let the initial pair of numbers be (1,1). Our task is to find number k, that is, the least number of steps needed to transform (1,1) into the pair where at least one number equals n.
I solved it by finding all the possible pairs and then return min steps in which the given number is formed, but it taking quite long time to compute.I guess this must be somehow related with finding gcd.can some one please help or provide me some link for the concept.
Here is the program that solved the issue but it is not cleat to me...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define INF 1000000000

int n,r=INF;

int f(int a,int b){

  if(b<=0)return INF;
  if(a>1&&b==1)return a-1;
  return f(b,a-a/b*b)+a/b;

}


int main(){

  cin>>n;
  for(int i=1;i<=n/2;i++){
    r=min(r,f(n,i));
  }
  cout<<(n==1?0:r)<<endl;

}
```

Comment: what is the constraint for n? Also do you need the actual steps or only their number?

Comment: @izomorphius n is <5000 and i need only the minimum steps..

Comment: It is somehow related with gcd , but i am not able to figure out..

Answer (score 1):

My approach to such problems(one I got from projecteuler.net) is to calculate the first few terms of the sequence and then search in oeis for a sequence with the same terms. This can result in a solutions order of magnitude faster. In your case the sequence is probably: http://oeis.org/A178031 but unfortunately it has no easy to use formula.
:
As the constraint for n is relatively small you can do a [dp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) on the minimum number of steps required to get to the pair (a,b) from (1,1). You take a two dimensional array that stores the answer for a given pair and then you do a recursion with memoization:

```
int mem[5001][5001];
int solve(int a, int b) {
  if (a == 0) {
     return mem[a][b] = b + 1;
  }
  if (mem[a][b] != -1) {
    return mem[a][b];
  }
  if (a == 1 && b == 1) {
    return mem[a][b] = 0;
  }
  int res;
  if (a > b) {
    swap(a,b);
  }
  if (mem[a][b%a] == -1) { // not yet calculated
    res = solve(a, b%a);
  } else { // already calculated
    res = mem[a][b%a];
  }
  res += b/a;
  return mem[a][b] = res;
}


int main() {
  memset(mem, -1, sizeof(mem));
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int best = -1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    int temp = solve(n, i);
    if (best == -1 || temp < best) {
      best = temp;
    }
  }
  cout << best << endl;
}
```

In fact in this case there is not much difference between dp and BFS, but this is the general approach to such problems. Hope this helps.

EDIT: return a big enough value in the dp if a is zero

Answer (score 0):

You can use the breadth first search algorithm to do this. At each step you generate all possible NEXT steps that you havent seen before. If the set of next steps contains the result you're done if not repeat. The number of times you repeat this is the minimum number of transformations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the maximum number you can get after k-3 steps is kth fibinocci number. Let t be the magic ratio.

Now, for n start with (n, upper(n/t) ).

```
If x>y:
    NumSteps(x,y) = NumSteps(x-y,y)+1
Else:
    NumSteps(x,y) = NumSteps(x,y-x)+1
```

Iteratively calculate NumSteps(n, upper(n/t) )

PS: Using upper(n/t) might not always provide the optimal solution. You can do some local search around this value for the optimal results. To ensure optimality you can try ALL the values from 0 to n-1, in which worst case complexity is O(n^2). But, if the optimal value results from a value close to upper(n/t), the solution is O(nlogn)